# Plotly and JupyterLab: graphs not showing from remote server

Tags: ssh, plotly, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am using a JupyterLab server that I am connecting to via ssh port forwarding. For some reason, Plotly graphs don't show up. Instead of the image, all I get the textual description of the FigureWidget:

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [2,5,6,1,-5]

go.FigureWidget(data=[{'x':x, 'y':y}])
```

output:

```
Figure({
'data': [{'type': 'scatter',
          'uid': '2aae0f73-7b85-4dc7-8551-7a1393d1e3c8',
          'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
          'y': [2, 5, 6, 1, -5]}],
'layout': {}
})
```

This is how I connect to the server:

```
ssh -N -f -L 8888:localhost:9000 user@server
```

And this is how I started the server:

```
jupyter lab --port=9000 --no-browser
```

**Edit:**

It seems to run fine with Firefox but not with Chrome.

Comment: Do you mind to provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I don't see how the code you posted could eventually show a plot.

Comment: There was a typo: It has to be `FigureWidget`. According to the docs, this code should produce a plot https://plot.ly/python/figurewidget/

Comment: Now it makes sense.